# My server 2012 is very slow due to Expl0er.exe file?

Tags: windows, memory, virus, windows-server-2012

I have Windows Server 2012. I faced some slow issue due to `Expl0er.exe` file and its located in

> `C:\Program Data\Expl0er.exe`

I don't know about the file.
its take more CPU usage up to more then 70% CPU, and its take less ram memory.
please help anyone let us know its virus or any other file or explain about the file. Thank you

Comment: Did you have a look at the file? Did you install it? Did you check it using something like virustotal?

Comment: i did not installed anything.

Comment: Sounds like a virus. You should check for viruses and malware. Keep in mind, that if you have RDP port 3389 open, it is likely your server got hacked and a cryptolocker virus is installed.

Comment: I don't know but in task manager its UserName shows Mssqlserver. I want to know more details about this file.

Comment: friend, please note its not a explore.exe. its expl0re.exe

Comment: Yes, exactly. Explorer.exe is normal for windows. expl0er.exe is not, which is most likely a virus, especially if its in C:\Program Data. So again, scan for viruses. If you don't want to do that, then why post a question on SuperUser?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks totally like a virus.

- Its name mimics the legitimate `explorer.exe`, but not exactly.
- It's in `ProgramData`, which is a folder dedicated for program data (obviously), not programs themselves. Why would a real program install in there? A virus could, though, because it likely doesn't have administrator rights which are required to install in `Program Files`.
- Programs usually install in dedicated per-program folders, not directly into system folders.
- etc.

It looks like the infected machine is a server, possibly an important one. Now it has been compromised. It means that **you can no longer trust this machine**. You don't know what the virus did: which configuration changes it made, what other malware it installed etc.

You should:

1. Immediately disconnect the machine from network to prevent other computers from infection and other nasty actions taken by malware.
2. [Nuke the infected server from orbit](https://serverfault.com/q/218005), reinstall from scratch and restore backups. [Yes, it's necessary.](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/24195/68614)

Let me emphasize that [it's not worth attempting to remove the malware](https://superuser.com/a/512901/194694) because you can never be sure that you succeeded. **You should also find out how the malware got onto server in the first place.** Viruses don't appear out of thin air. It could have been:

- downloaded by something/someone (intentionally or not)
- carried over on an thumb drive
- it may have "jumped" to the server over the network

Anyway, it's very likely that other machines that interact with that server are infected and you'll have to deal with them too.